# Download file to browser using .NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

Using ASP.NET Razor Pages, I am trying download a file to the browser.
From the Page(html), using a link like this works fine:

```
href="/DownloadableFiles/testB.csv" download="newname">Download Link
```

However, I want to initiate the download from the code-behind or `ViewModel` so it can be dynamic as to what the filename is, I also need to inspect the file first, etc.

In ASP.NET MVC core, (not RazorPages) you can download a file in code using:

```
return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
```

But `return File` is not supported in Razor Pages.

Comment: The return File exists and I can use it in a razor page.

Answer (score 18):

pitaridis is correct, `return File` exists in Razor Pages, I must have been missing a namespace.
This will download a file from Code Behind:

In the page, here's the submit button:

```
<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="DownloadFile" style="width:75px" 
        class="cancel"> Download </button>
```

In the PageModel (code behind):

```cs
public ActionResult OnPostDownloadFile()
{
    return File("/DownloadableFiles/TestFile34.csv", "application/octet-stream", 
                "NewName34.csv");
}
```

Note:
/DownloadableFiles is in a subfolder of wwwroot

Comment: in aspnet core we can also stop hard-coding these media types: `MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet`

Answer (score 7):

It's also possible to use a GET call instead of POST like this:

Put this in your page code behind:

```
public ActionResult OnGetDownload()
{
  return File("c:/Directory/FileName.csv", "application/octet-stream", "FileName.csv");
}
```

And put this on that page:

```
 <a href="@Url.Page("ThePageName", "Download")>Download</a>
```

If you want to pass parameters, just include them in the Url.Page call and add parameters to OnGetDownload like this:

```
public ActionResult OnGetDownload(int Id)
{
  return File("c:/Directory/FileName.csv", "application/octet-stream", "FileName.csv");
}

<a href="@Url.Page("ThePageName", "Download", new { Model.Id })">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to download a produced file in the OnPost handler of a Razor page. The trick was to produce a path relative path to wwwroot. This is what worked for me:

```
public async Task<FileResult> OnPost()
{
    var pathToZipOnDisk = ProduceFile();
    ...
    return File($"~/export/{Path.GetFileName(pathToZipOnDisk)}", 
        "application/zip", 
        "download.zip");
}
```