# How can I write the following for the asp.net core 8 razor pages Responses?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-8

I want to write the following code for the asp.net core 8 environment.

```
 Response.Buffer = true;


 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=license.txt");
 
 Response.ContentType = "application/text";

 Response.Output.Write(data);
 Response.Flush();
 
 Response.End();
```

I managed to add header by the following line.

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "filename=license.txt";
```

Comment: What type is `data`? A `string`? `byte[]`? Something else? And are you working with MVC controllers, Razor Pages `PageModel` or minimal API request handlers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file to browser using .NET Core Razor Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952832/download-file-to-browser-using-net-core-razor-pages)

Comment: What's the *real* question? How to return a text file? In your handler use `return File(...,"application/text","license.txt")`. The missing part depends on what `data` is. If the file is static though, you should probably look at the [Static Files middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: @MikeBrind data is type of string. and I am using razor pages PageModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handler method, you only need the following to replace what you posted:

```
return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), "application/text", "licence.txt");
```

You might need to add a `using` directive for `System.Text`:

```
using System.Text;
```